# How to create a custom Docker image and use it as a GitLab CI/CD Service?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cloud-foundry, ssh-tunnel

I'm using CloudFoundry for deploying my services, and my E2E tests are done with Postman (Newman on CLI). The situation is that I do not have access directly to some services from my GitLab CI/CD, then I need to create an SSH Tunneling (cf ssh) to be able to execute the Postman collections through the tunneling during the CI/CD pipeline.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-private-registry/cf-cli-image

COPY ./images/cf-ssh-tunnel-service/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 9001

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

and this is the `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
        exit 1
    fi
    local val="$def"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
        val="${!var}"
    elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
    fi
    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}

file_env 'CF_SSH_SERVICE_APP_NAME'
file_env 'CF_SSH_SERVICE_REMOTE_PORT' 8080
CF_SSH_SERVICE_LOCAL_PORT=9001

echo "Logging in ..."
cf login -a $CF_URL -u $CF_DEPLOY_USER -p $CF_DEPLOY_PASSWORD -o $CF_ORG -s $CF_SPACE --skip-ssl-validation
cf target

echo "Creating the CF SSH Tunnel to $CF_SSH_SERVICE_APP_NAME:$CF_SSH_SERVICE_REMOTE_PORT though the local port $CF_SSH_SERVICE_LOCAL_PORT."
cf ssh -k -T -N $CF_SSH_SERVICE_APP_NAME -L $CF_SSH_SERVICE_LOCAL_PORT:0.0.0.0:$CF_SSH_SERVICE_REMOTE_PORT
echo "DONE!"
```

and finally this is how I'm using the image as a service in the GitLab Pipeline:

```
stages:
    - e2e-test

newman:test:development:
  image: my-private-registry/curl-image
  stage: e2e-test
  services:
    - name: my-private-registry/cf-ssh-tunnel-service:latest
      alias: cf-ssh-tunnel-service
  variables:
    CF_SSH_SERVICE_APP_NAME: $APP_NAME
  script:
    - curl http://cf-ssh-tunnel-service:9001/endpoint
```

as you can see I'm creating the service based on that image. Then when I run the pipeline, the `curl` request returns a `Could not resolve host: cf-ssh-tunnel-service`.

Q: How can I create a Docker image to be used as a service in GitLab?
Q: How should I create that CF SSH Tunnel to work as a listening service for GitLab?

Comment: Can you update your post to include a failing job output? Does that show some of your 'echo' statements from the service? Also, given all of the env variables in the entrypoint script, I'm assuming you're setting those environment variables in GitLab CI as secret variables? It might also be helpful to enable debugging - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#debug-tracing

Answer (score 0):

Unless your image is stored in a [GitLab container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/) you won't be able to access your custom images (as it requires a login to the private repo in order to be able to pull it).

I can think about two solutions:

1. [Creating a custom docker runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) on a personal machine:

```sh
sudo gitlab-runner register

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com )
https://gitlab.com

Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner
xxx

Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner
[hostname] my-runner

Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
my-tag,another-tag

Please enter the executor: ssh, docker+machine, docker-ssh+machine, kubernetes, docker, parallels, virtualbox, docker-ssh, shell:
docker

Please enter the Docker image (eg. ruby:2.1):
alpine:latest
```

A few notes here:

- you may find your gitlab-ci token in your project in Settings > CI/CD > Runners
- Gitlab-runner register needs you to specify a default docker image (in case you call the runner without specifying the image to use) but it'll use the image you tell it to use.

Should you choose that option, you will have to add the `tags: [docker-runner-tag]` command to your job in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Don't forget to perform a docker login on the machine from which you have registered your custom docker runner, otherwise the pull will still fail. It's possible you'll have to [add gitlab-runner to the group of docker's authorized users](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) as well:

`sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner`

2. [Create a GitLab container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/). I have never used that option so I won't go into details, but you should find instructions to create a brand new container registry in the Packages > Container Registry section in your project.

I think Docker Hub also offers options for private registries but I don't know whether such services would be free to use.